# Ternary operator precedence and assignment

Tags: c++, c++11, ternary-operator

I have an unusual bug in my code, where sometimes, my code will return the wrong value. I have a ternary expression in a function which may be the culprit, and it's written like this;

```
corpusBoard[i][j] = (piece == 'o') ? 'o' : 'x';
```

Which should state, if `piece` is equal to 'o', then assign 'o' to `corpusBoard[i][j]`, otherwise assign 'x' to `corpusBoard[i][j]`.

Are these two statements below equivalent? If not, why?

```
corpusBoard[i][j] = (piece == 'o') ? 'o' : 'x';
corpusBoard[i][j] = ((piece == 'o') ? 'o' : 'x');
```

**Edit:**

The particular issue I'm having is with a project I'm working on, where the system checks a database of sorts for matches, then instantiates player pieces to characters in the database. As the pieces can be either 'o' or 'x', I wanted a simple way to "flip" them when doing a pattern match in the database:

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> Machine::matchCorpus(std::vector<std::vector<char>> corpusBoard)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < corpusBoard.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < corpusBoard[0].size(); j++){
            if(corpusBoard[i][j] == 'M'){
               corpusBoard[i][j] = ((piece == 'o') ? 'x' : 'o');
            }
            if(corpusBoard[i][j] == 'H'){
                corpusBoard[i][j] = ((piece == 'o') ? 'o' : 'x');
            }

        }

    }
    return corpusBoard;
}
```

Unfortunately, in very rare cases, it returns the wrong value, even though if piece is 'o', and `corpusBoard[i][j] == 'H'`, it should always assign `corpusBoard[i][j]` to 'o', but rarely, it gets assigned 'x' instead.

Comment: @donjuedo: it's a char.

Comment: Your question, literally, is only about equivalence.  But your bug sounds interesting.  Care to reduce your project to a minimal example?

Comment: @donjuedo: I'll paste the full function into my question, but it's part of a bigger project I'm working on using Markov chains, so the bug could be elsewhere.

Comment: Have you put conditional printing before and after that last assignment, to confirm?  Is there threading going on elsewhere, so piece might change?

Comment: @donjuedo: Yeah, I just did that. It's happening elsewhere. One of my values isn't being converted before being entered into my database, and is being stored as an 'x', which is why I get the occasional erroneous result. At least I know where the problem is, now. Thanks for helping me rule this function out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are equivalent.  = comes last.